# SELECT statement using C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I have the following code:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(
  "SELECT ClaimId FROM tblPayment WHERE PaymentId = " + PaymentID.ToString(),
  mvarDBConn);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
Int32 ClaimId = reader.GetInt32(0);
reader.Close();
```

If I run the SELECT statement in SQL it returns the number fine, but when I use ExecuteReader all it returns is 0. I've tried multiple methods including ExecuteScalar, ExecuteNonQuery, reader.GetString then casting that to an int, etc.

What am I missing? Thanks.

EDIT: Here's what I get in the SQL Server Profile:

Here's what I get back:

```
 exec sp_executesql N'SELECT ClaimId FROM tblPayment WHERE PaymentId = @paymentID',N'@paymentID nvarchar(5)',@paymentID=N'8392'
```

Have no idea why it's putting it into an SP_ExecuteSQL when the previous SqlCommand I have goes straight to SQL, same with the 'N's.

Comment: What's the datatype of `ClaimId`?

Comment: Is the connection "mvarDBConn" opened?

Comment: **warning** your code maybe vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Are you sure `PaymentID` really contains the correct value?

Comment: When you run the query in mysql, which returns results?

Comment: PaymentID is correct, returns the correct value of 183703 (or whatever) in SQL. Type is an integer, connection is open.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Better to use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) for this:

```
int ClaimId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
```

Also, to avoid a possible [SQL Injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection), use ADO Command Object with Parameters:

```
// create command
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(
  "SELECT ClaimId FROM tblPayment WHERE PaymentId = @paymentID",
  mvarDBConn);

// add parameter
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paymentID", PaymentID);

// execute command and convert the result
int ClaimId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: No luck, it's still returning 0 for ClaimId. Thanks for the tip on preventing SQL injection, though.

Comment: @Feren6 - have you tried the query outside of your code?  I suspect that `Convert.ToInt()` will convert a `null` result into a `0` (zero) - _are you sure you have a `ClaimId` for the `PaymentId` you're testing?_

Comment: ToInt isn't a function of Convert, only Int16, Int32, and Int64 as options.

Comment: @Feren6: _"ToInt isn't a function of Convert"_ - Ahh, yes!  that should be `Convert.ToInt32()` - I've updated the answer

Comment: Stlil no luck with that. ClaimId and PaymentId are correct, if I run the SQL in SQL Server I get the result that I want. Hmm..

Comment: @Feren6 - At this point, I'd bust open the [SQL Server Profiler](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/03/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-profiler-2/) to see exactly what is getting sent to and executed by the database, then I'd copy that query from the Profiler and paste it into SQL Management Studio to see what the database is returning

Comment: The problem wasn't with the code -- when I was putting a breakpoint it didn't come out correctly, but the problem was with the Stored Procedure I was executing. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can try with

```
 new SqlCommand("SELECT ClaimId FROM tblPayment WHERE PaymentId = @param");
```

And

```
 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", PaymentID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run a while loop on the read.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Int32 ClaimId = reader.GetInt32(0);
}
```

Although, you might want to declare the ClaimId variable outside the while.